# Quickest way to copy Object Property with different name?

Tags: javascript

Is there a quicker (less lines of code) way to define these two properties with the same functions but different names?

```
Object.defineProperties(this, {
    "position": {
        get: function() {
            return "get";
        },
        set: function() {
            return "set";
        }
    },
    "pos": {
        get: function() {
            return "get";
        },
        set: function() {
            return "set";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want to keep the `get`ters & `set`ters I believe there isn't any other way.

Comment: Do you mean quicker in terms of writing lines of code? If they do really have exactly the same function but different property names you could probably build up that options object pragmatically and pass it to `Object.create`. But that would be a maintainability nightmare.

Comment: @ste2425 Yes, I do mean quicker as in lines of code. I may just define it like I originally did if there is no better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, depending on what you mean with quicker.

Here is a jsFiddle with some examples: https://jsfiddle.net/4o39yxmk/1/

```
var obj = {};

var props = {
        get: function() {
            return "get";
        },
        set: function(value) {
                console.log(value);
            return "set";
        }
    };

Object.defineProperties(obj, {
    "position": props,
    "pos": props
});

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'anotherPos', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'position'));

// trigger the setter
obj.position = 'myValuePosition';
obj.pos = 'myValuePos';
obj.anotherPos = 'myValueAnotherPos';

// trigger the getter
console.log(obj.position);
console.log(obj.pos);
console.log(obj.anotherPos);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the first property and then copy it to another name like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, {
    "position": {
        get: function() {
            return "get";
        },
        set: function() {
            return "set";
        }
    }
});
Object.defineProperty(this, 'pos', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, 'position'));
```